# How do I find the last memory link?

Tags: to-the-moon

I'm stuck on the memory where Johnny is just a boy, when his grandma call him "Joey". I already got 4 from the 5 links, but the red one I can't find.

[image: Johnny's memory]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the image you posted, I think you're missing the link which can be retrieved by standing on the center of the sofa. The sofa is on the right side of the image.

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly this point. Funny that I really tried to go clicking around, I think I misclicked this part of the scenario.